# In-app purchase (in my app) says: Google Play account not authenticated

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, in-app-purchase

I created an Android app and it has the in-app purchase workflow.

My question is not about programming but instead about the Google Play user account handling on Android devices.

When the purchase starts I get an error about the account having not been authenticated, and it says to sign in (this is a system message, it is not from my app).

My app has been previously tested with one single account and it worked. This version is not the same but nothing important has changed.

When I go to Google Play it seems that the account is already selected and working.

So what's the issue?

Comment: [see 23/12/15](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/play/jtoLWvt6Y8U/sut1c9AjCgAJ) post instructions and try that

Comment: @beeshyams I cleared data but it's the same, because Google Play does not ask me to sign in, it just wanted me to fill a checkbox.

Comment: Adding a snap shot may help